# iterating 2D array using parallel processing MPI

Tags: c, arrays, parallel-processing, mpi

i am quite new to parallel processing. I have an example of calculating and storing elements of a 2D array in a sequential way. I wanted to convert this into a parallel program using MPI.

Following is the code for sequential program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int x,y,xMax=10,yMax=10;
int main ()
{
  int arr[yMax][xMax];
  for(y =0; y<yMax;x++)
  {
      for (x=0;x<xMax;x++)
      {
         arr[y][x]=x+y;
         printf("%d",arr[y][x]);
      }
      printf("\n");
  }
}
```

I tried to convert this to an equivalent MPI program by parallelizing the outer for loop as follows:
Here I want every process to calculate values for each array row and send the output array to root process which at the end will gather all the arrays and combine them into single 2D array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>
int x,y,xMax=10,yMax=10,size,rank;
int main()
{
   int arr[xMax];
   int arrall[yMax][xMax];  
   MPI_Init(NULL,NULL);
   MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
   MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
   for(y =0+rank; y<yMax;y=y+size)
   {
      for (x=0;y<xMax;x++)
      {
         arr[y][x]=x+y;

      }
      MPI_Send(arr,xMax,MPI_INT,0,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
   }
  if(rank==0)
  {
  MPI_Gather(arr,xMax,MPI_INT,&arrall,xMax*yMax,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  }  
  MPI_Finalize();
}
```

But when i compile the program and wait quite a while for it but it still does not give any result. and it does not show the errors.
I am trying on this for quite some time and searched for the any solution but unable to find. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually thinking too complicated. The collective operations in MPI take care of both the sending and receiving part. As mark writes, point to point messages such as `MPI_Send` will only match with point to point messages (e.g. `MPI_Recv`), and collectives only match with the same collective.

The whole communication is done with the a single call to `MPI_Gather` for all processes:

```
MPI_Gather(arr,xMax,MPI_INT,arrall,xMax,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Notice, that the `recvcount` is `xMax`, because it specifies the number of elements in every single receive.

Some more remarks:

- You have to ensure that `size == yMax`
- This only works because 2D arrays are layed out row-wise contiguously in memory. This does not work with pointer-"2D"-arrays.
- In a real MPI program, you want to avoid gathering the whole working data on a single rank, as it presents a limit for scalability. Instead you should do everything distributed.

Edit: One specific way for more than one row per rank:

```
int rows_per_rank = yMax / size;
assert(rows_per_rank * size == yMax);
MPI_Gather(arr,xMax * rows_per_rank,MPI_INT,arrall,xMax * rows_per_rank,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Comment: thank you! what will be the size of output? will it be a 2D array ?

Comment: `arrall` will be filled with `size * xMax` elements. The "output" will match the data layout of the 2D array.

Comment: "You have to ensure that size == yMax" can you please help me to overcome this issue? I cannot give task to 1000 processes if yMax = 1000. Thanks

Comment: If you want to have more than one row per rank, say `rows_per_rank * rank == size`, just replace the send/recv size parameters of `MPI_Gather` from `xMax` to `xMax * rows_per_rank`.

Comment: Just for trying I divided 10 rows data among 5 processes. And multiply send/rec with 2. But I cannot gather data correctly. I am getting some large numbers some with negative sign instead of original data. Though I noticed that last row of each process I got correctly.

Comment: @Max I added an example code that works with more than one row per rank.

Comment: @Zulan, can you suggest possible solution to fix the issue in the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72522846/valueerror-could-not-broadcast-input-array-from-shape-2-450-450-into-shape-4/72538180#72538180